# Export Excel values to HTML using VB.Net

Tags: html, excel, vb.net

I have a Windows Forms with button click operation.

On button click the specified columns in excel should be exported to html.

I used "SaveAs" method. But not able to open the file format in any browser. Please help me how to export specific columns('B','D') to hmtl with cell color.

```
Dim xlApp As Excel.Application

Dim xlWB As Excel.WorkBook

Dim xlSH As Excel.WorkSheet

Dim str_File As String = "C:\Sample.xlsx"

xlApp = New Excel.Application

xlWB = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(str_File)

xlSH = xlWB.WorkSheets("merge")

xlSH.SaveAs("C:\Sample.html")
```

Comment: Changing the extension will not convert an Excel worksheet to HTML.

Answer (score 0):

Just add the `FileFormat` paramater to the `.SaveAs` method and Bob's your uncle. I also closed and quit the Workbook and Application respectively. I added the GC code to the calling method to get rid of ghost Excel when debugging.

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    OpCode()
    GC.Collect()
    GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers()
End Sub

Private Sub OpCode()
    Dim str_File As String = "C:\Users\xxx\Documents\Excel\Politics\2020 Election.xlsx"
    Dim xlApp As New Excel.Application
    Dim xlWB As Excel.Workbook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(str_File)
    Dim xlSH As Excel.Worksheet = CType(xlWB.Worksheets(1), Excel.Worksheet)
    xlSH.SaveAs("C:\Users\xxx\Documents\Excel\Sample.html", Excel.XlFileFormat.xlHtml)
    xlWB.Close()
    xlApp.Quit()
End Sub
```

Comment: Is there any other approach other than SaveAs?

Comment: Why? Is this not working for you? This seems very simple.

Comment: I need like an actual html page. I need few more details need to be added like title for the page making it centre, followed by the column values from excel as tabular using VB.Net for windows application. Can you please help in that?

Comment: That is what you have in the .html file.

Comment: But it cannot be edited in VB na? Any changes I need to change in excel.

Comment: I answered your question and you have not accepted my answer. You keep asking new questions. Now you want to open the file. Try `Process.Start("C:\Users\xxx\Documents\Excel\Sample.html")`